# How connect client to server with feathers js authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, feathersjs

this is my server.js:

```
app.use('/users', {
    find(params) {
      return Promise.resolve(Users);
    }
  });
  app.service('authentication').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [
      auth.hooks.authenticate(['local', 'jwt'])
    ]
  }
});
app.service('users').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [
      local.hooks.hashPassword()
    ]
  }
});
/////////////////
app.post('/login', auth.express.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/app', failureRedirect: '/login' }));

app.get('/app', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ success: true });
});

app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ success: false });
});
//////////////
```

please who can help me if i have an error in my code ? and what i should do in my file in frontend ? I work with reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of **connecting clients** with feathersjs auth.

The easest way ( React/ Angular /... ) without using particular libraries:

> Do a **post request** to the **auth url**: http://Your_url:port/authentication.

**Body**:

> {     email: email,
>           password: password,
>           strategy: "local"
>         }

If your request success, you will get a **response** with an **accessToken**.
So, you should save that token and use it to access protected routes.

**IMPORTANT**: using "email" attr, because its the default auth attr. You can configure it as you wish.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I work with reactjs and it seems i have some issues with using my accessToken to access protected routes created with react router.

Answer (score 0):

In feathersjs having default authentication(login) api something like this.

**Url:**    http://localhost:8080/authentication

**method:** Post

**Body:**  `{"strategy": "local","email":"admin@xyz.com","password":"admin123"}`

Than you will get Token which you expected.

**response:**

```
{
    "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImFjY291bnRJZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTE",
    "code": 200,
    "authentication": "user login successful"
}
```

After that add this token to all other api calls in Headers Authorization equal to token.

[image]